# metadata could not be determined because stored procedure contains dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, openrowset

I have a stored procedure that contains some dynamic SQL. I am trying to execute the stored procedure using `OPENROWSET` but am getting the error:

> Msg 11514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1
>
> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_out INT OUTPUT', @row_count_out = @row_count_table OUTPUT;' in procedure 'nachoTest'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.

My real stored procedure is a bit more complex but this is a working example of the error:

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nachoTest  @table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @row_count_table INT
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT @row_count_out = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @table_name
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@row_count_out INT OUTPUT', @row_count_out = @row_count_table OUTPUT;

    SELECT @row_count_table AS row_count, @table_name AS table_name
END
GO
```

Calling it with `OPENROWSET`

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC dbo.nachoTest ''e_MFA_All_Tokens''')
```

I have read a bit online but cannot figure out how to use `WITH RESULT SETS` to fix the code. Ideally I'd like to fix the stored procedure but if I have to change the `OPENROWSET` call then that is okay too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not in your proc but in `OPENROWSET`/`OPENQUERY`.
Prior to SQL Server 2012 to figure out the resultset metadata `set fmtonly` was used. Starting with 2012 it was replaced by `sp_describe_first_result_set` that causes this error.

here how you can describe your resultset:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC dbo.nachoTest ''e_MFA_All_Tokens'' WITH RESULT SETS
(
  (
    cnt int, name sysname
  )
)')
```

More on `EXECUTE WITH RESULT SETS` here: [SQL Server 2012 T-SQL at a Glance – EXECUTE WITH RESULT SETS](http://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server-2012-t-sql-glance-execute-result-sets)

Comment: I see. And there is no way to modify the stored procedure to provide that data somehow?

Comment: Because I intend to use this to `INSERT INTO #temptable SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET...`. Right now I am using `INSERT INTO #temptable EXEC ...` but with that I have to create #temptable beforehand. I want to use `INSERT INTO` so I don't have to create the table before hand but if `OPENROWSET` requires the table schema then it is the same as just creating the table before hand.